# How do can I easily implement a visually interactive tree data structure using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, treeview

The closest thing to what I am looking for is this:

http://www.qmatica.com/DataStructures/Trees/AVL/AVLTree.html

Notice how it lets the user insert or delete nodes by clicking on buttons.

The problem with the above link is it is implemented in Flash, not Javascript. 
Also, instead of clicking on "Insert" or "Delete" buttons I want the user to be able to drag and drop nodes into or out of the tree.

I would appreciate it if somebody could let me know of any Javascript vector graphic libraries that do something like this.

Comment: Maybe the [jit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/demos.html) library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need something like that tree? I have used nestable for the same purposes and find it better looking and usable. Check this out http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/